# Object browser in SSMS 2008 doesn't work if I don't have access to all databases

Tags: sql-server, hosting, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008, if I log into a shared hosting provider with many databases on one server, I cannot use the Object Explorer. This worked fine in 2005. Anyway to change this behavior?

It throws this exception:

- The server principal "myusername" is not able to access the database "first-database-alphabetically-on-shared-server" under the current security context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

click View, Object Explorer Details. Then, open Databases. Finally, click the header columns and uncheck Collation.

Source: https://sqlblog.org/2008/07/07/a-little-management-studio-oops

I solved this for my own machine a while ago and had to look the issue back up.  Hopefully this link and the links from there will help you find the answer if this doesn't.  It seems familiar to what i had to do.

Comment: I ran into this as well - THANK YOU - I never would have dug that deep to figure it out on my own! +10000

Comment: This solves the initial problem however have you tried right clicking the database -> tasks -> script database fails with the same error trying to script a database you have access to.

Comment: perhaps you should ask another question regarding that issue @petebob796

Comment: Same problem here... I'm using sql server express 2008, and, upon creating a login for one of my databases, and logging in with it, I couldn't view the databases tree (although I could execute queries)... Well, solved with this info :) Thanks!